# Listener reloads value of flag for every parameter change

Tags: java

I have a listener for parameter change event and flag=0, problem is when 2 parameters are changed at a time there are 2 calls for listener , for the first parameter call flag=1is updated for the use of other parameters ,but listener is reloaded with flag=0

i tried to call it outside postcall

```
public class JobListener<adminFlag> implements EventListener {
     int adminFlag =0;
    @Override
    public void postCall(final Event event, final Object object) throws ListenerException, RemoteException {
    if(parameter is category)
    {
    adminFlag =1;
    }
    
    if(parameter is user)
    {
      if(adminFlag !=1)
      some code;
    }
}
```

this remains 1 for every other update also ,how can i fix this .
or
any other way ,to do this.

Comment: you can pass flag in event itself

Comment: What other technologies in addition to pure java are involved? Java has a `java.util.EventListener` interface, but it cannot be the one referenced in the question - `java.util.EventListener` contains no `postCall()` method

Comment: can you please provide example how can it be passed in event